# Allow specific user to edit a specific page

Tags: php, users, capabilities

I've tried to make a script that only allows a specific user to edit a specific page but without any success.

The idea behind, is that if a users username contains a specific word, they are allowed to edit a special page.

I've tried to do this, by granting the specific users a special capability, and then checking that capability when opening the special page.

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_login = $current_user->data->user_login;

    if( strpos($user_login, '@special-domain.com') !== false ) {
        $user = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
        $user->add_cap('edit_special_page');
    }
});

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', function( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if ( 'edit_page' == $cap && user_can( $user_id, 'edit_special_page' ) )
    {
        $post_id = $args[0];
        $special_page_id = get_page_by_path('special-page') ? get_page_by_path('special-page')->ID : null;

        if ( special_page_id == $post_id ) {
            $caps = [];
            $caps[] = 'edit_special_page';
        }
    }
    return $caps;
}, 10, 4 );
```

But all users can still edit to the special page, which should only be possible for users with *@special-domain.com* in their usernames.
I've also tried to use the **post-id** directly instead of `$special_page_id`, but with the same result.

Any idea why this is not working and how to do it?

PS: I am **NOT** interested in any kind of plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that an empty return value from `map_meta_cap` will grant *all* users permission to do that thing, because that's essentially the same thing as saying "no capabilities are required to do this". What you really want to do is just add `edit_special_page` to the existing list of required capabilities:

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', function( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    if ( 'edit_post' === $cap || 'edit_page' === $cap ) {
        $current_page_id = $args[0];
        $special_page_id = get_page_by_path( 'special-page' ) ? get_page_by_path( 'special-page' )->ID : null;

        // If the page being edited is the special page...
        if ( $special_page_id === $current_page_id ) {
            // ... the user must have the edit_special_page capability.
            $caps[] = 'edit_special_page';
        }
    }

    return $caps;
}, 10, 4 );
```

An unrelated issue, but something that you'll need to address, is that you shouldn't add capabilities on `admin_init` or `init`. Adding capabilities writes to the database, so its only something that should be done once of plugin/theme activation or when the user is registered:

```
add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ( strpos( $user->user_login, '@special-domain.com' ) !== false ) {
        $user->add_cap( 'edit_special_page' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But all users still have access and can make edits to the special page. If I try to print_r($cap), I can a large list of capabilities, but 'edit-page' is not one of them

Comment: Where are you printing it? You're only going to see `edit_page` if that capability is currently being checked.

Comment: I'm printing it on the post-edit page.

Comment: I've updated my answer. In some cases WordPress core checks the `edit_post` meta capability, regardless of the post type, so you'll need to apply the check for that capability too.

Comment: Than you very much. Now it seems to work perfectly :)